# Change style of element which appears directly before another element on the same level

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My issue is as follows:
I've got a navigation bar with main navigation and some of these links have additional drop down menus.
I'm trying to change the styling of the main link, whenever I hover over the drop down menu.
I can't use classes as it will change the style of all the main nav links. Which means I can't use the following method

```
.dropdown:hover ~ .main{
    change css here
}
```

I also can't use individual IDs for the linked drop down and main nav as it appears on too many pages already.

The format of the HTML is as follows

```
<a class="main-link">Main Link</a>
<div class="drop-down"></div>
```

My question is; is there a way to change the style of an element which appears directly before an element within a HTML document?

Comment: What effect you want to achieve? Provide SO Snippet with menu structure and css

Comment: If you're still struggling, I would suggest [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27993987/2117156). Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/axLkp74k/) too